# Array size should be known at compile time

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, static-memory-allocation

I wrote a simple code where I am creating array without a fixed size. I tried compiling the code in `gcc` and it is working fine. Please explain why this is working array size should be supposed to be known at compile time.

Here's the code I have used.

```
void f(int k)
{
   int a[k];
   .....//some operation
}

int main()
{
  int i = 10;
  f(10);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: Why this above code is working?

Comment: Array size here is depended on variable and which is right now parameter of the function, and when this will be evoked, at run time space will be allocated to it not on compile time.

Comment: @tor it works in case of gcc.

Comment: yes it works in gcc, my doubt was why it works but it seems now newer version of C allows this as pointed out by others..anyways thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This feature is known as `VLA` or variable length array. This is not supported in all C standards. In recent C standards like  `C11` and `C99`, it is supported, but not in older C Standards as 'C89'.

If you're using `gcc`, please have a look at the [compiler documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) regarding this.

Comment: What is also worth to mention: this feature is not suported by MSVC they simply deny to support VLA's in their compiler. This is one of the reasons why the Visual C of Microsoft isn't allowed to call it self  plain C.